# Calculate current probability in respect to prior probabilities to get uniform distribution

Tags: ruby, statistics, probability, probability-theory

*Disclaimer: not sure if title of question is accurate...*

Let's say I need to wash the dishes within the next 100 minutes. I know I **MUST** do it after 100 minutes as the latest. I ask myself every 2 minutes "should I do it or not?" (so I ask myself a total of 50 times). Each time I ask myself if I should do it or not, I wanna calculate a probability of me doing it, that will then determine if I do it now or not. The probability should be so that if I repeat the experiment a million times, then I would get an almost even likelihood of me doing it after 2 minutes, 4 minutes, 6 minutes etc. etc. - or in other words a uniform distribution of the probability of doing it.

I have made an experiment where I set the individual probability to `check_number / total_number_of_checks` However this does not seem to give the right result. Any ideas?

```
# gem install ascii_charts
require 'ascii_charts'

time_frame = 100
check_frequenzy = 2
number_of_checks = time_frame / check_frequenzy

checks = (1..number_of_checks)

result = {}
checks.each do |i|
  result[i] = 0
end

10_000.times do |t|
  checks.each do |check_number|
    probability = check_number/number_of_checks.to_f
    if rand() <= probability
      # Oh no! I need to do the dishes now :-(
      result[check_number] += 1
      break
    end
  end
end

puts AsciiCharts::Cartesian.new(result.to_a).draw

#=>

950|                                                                                                                                                      
900|                *  *  *                                                                                                                               
850|                         *                                                                                                                            
800|             *                                                                                                                                        
750|                            *                                                                                                                         
700|          *                                                                                                                                           
650|                               *                                                                                                                      
600|       *                          *                                                                                                                   
550|                                                                                                                                                      
500|                                     *                                                                                                                
450|                                                                                                                                                      
400|    *                                                                                                                                                 
350|                                        *                                                                                                             
300|                                           *                                                                                                          
250|                                                                                                                                                      
200| *                                            *                                                                                                       
150|                                                 *                                                                                                    
100|                                                    *                                                                                                 
 50|                                                       *  *  *                                                                                        
  0+----------------------------------------------------------------*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*--*-
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I would get an almost even likelihood of me doing it after 2 minutes, 4 minutes, 6 minutes etc"? So far I understand you have a random variable that can take on values 1 to 50, but I don't understand the rule for creating the distribution.

Comment: What do you mean by "*joint* probability should be *linear*"? Firsly, "joint" implies that there is more than one random variable, but I am only aware of one: the time (in minutes) when the dishes are washed (call that `T`).  By "linear" do you mean `P[T <= t]  = .01*t`?

Comment: @eigenchris If you look at the plot that comes from the above code then it's far from ideal. It shows that if I calculate each individual probability of "doing the dishes" as: the number of time I ask my self (x) divided by the total number of times I can ask my self (50), then in most cases I will end up doing the dishes after around 14 minutes (7. time I ask my self). HOWEVER I want to calculate the individual probabilities so that I end up with a distribution that is way more "even" - ideally linear (don't think that is possible in statistics though).

Comment: @CarySwoveland Sorry, I might be using the wrong words (I'm not too good at the theoretical therms). Does my above comment clarify? If so, please feel free to edit the question

Comment: @NielsKristian I'm still a little unsure. Do you want a uniform distribution, that is where the probability of doing the dishes at a given time is 1/50? I'm not sure what you mean by "linear"...

Comment: @eigenchris YES exacty - "uniform distribution" is probably the right word! :-)

Comment: @NielsKristian You could generate samples just by using the `rand()` function. `2*(rand(50)+1)` will generate an even number between `2` and `100` with equal probability.

Comment: @eigenchris The problem is, that I can not determine WHEN I should do it up front. I need to do it on the fly. So after 2 minutes I ask myself: do it / don't do it? with x probability of doing it. Then if the decision is to NOT do it, then I wait another 2 minutes and ask myself again. I do this until I either decide to do it or 100 minutes has past. If I have not done it after the deadline (100 minutes) then I'll be forced to do it.

Comment: @NielsKristian I understand. I'll write up an answer in the next few minutes.

Comment: I don't really understand why you'd want to estimate the probability distribution by simulation when you can compute it directly.

Comment: This is because I have a system where I have completely decoupled myself from scheduling actions in the future. This is convenient since it is very resilient to failures. Long story

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `N` opportunities to accomplish a task, with each opportunity having an equal probability of `1/N`, you can pick a random opportunity on-the-fly using the following algorithm. (I don't know Ruby so I used pseudocode.)

```
for i from 1 to N
    r = random integer from 0 to N-i inclusive
    if r == 0
        return 2*i  // wash dishes now, at the ith opportunity (2*i minutes)
                    // otherwise continue the loop
```

For the case of `N=50`, this means the first opportunity has a probability of `p(1) = 1/50`. Afterward, the second opportunity has probability `p(2) = 1/49`. After this, `p(3) = 1/48`, ans so on until `p(50) = 1/1`, meaning we must do the task at the last opportunity if we haven't already.

---

We can confirm this gives a uniform probability for each opportunity just by multiplying the individual probabilities up until a given point. For example, the chance of taking the 4th opportunity...

- the probability of **not** doing the task on the 1st opportunity is `49/50`
- the probability of **not** doing the task on the 2nd opportunity is `48/49`
- the probability of **not** doing the task on the 3rd opportunity is `47/48`
- the probability of **doing** the task on the 4th opportunity is `1/47`

The product would be `49/50 * 48/49 * 47/48 * 1/47 = 1/50`, as desired.

---

In other words: `probability = check_number/number_of_checks.to_f` needs to be changed to: `probability = 1.0/(number_of_checks - check_number)`

This will render:

```
260|                                                                                                                *                                     
240|                                           *                                                                       *                                  
220|             *                                *  *              *              *     *              *     *  *        *  *  *              *  *       
200| *  *  *  *           *  *              *           *  *  *  *     *  *  *  *           *        *     *                       *  *              *    
180|                *  *        *  *  *  *                                            *        *  *                                      *  *             
160|                                                                                                                                                      
140|                                                                                                                                                      
120|                                                                                                                                                      
100|                                                                                                                                                      
 80|                                                                                                                                                      
 60|                                                                                                                                                      
 40|                                                                                                                                                      
 20|                                                                                                                                                      
  0+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*-
     1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50
```

---

If you are especially curious, you can actually generate a uniform distribution even if you don't know number of opportunities `N` ahead of time. See [reservoir sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling) for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe you could edit my question to make it a bit more "correctly" written? Especially the title maybe :-)

Comment: @NielsKristian Sure. I'm busy now, but I'll get to it later.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate those conditional probabilities using [Bayes' Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem).

Let `T` be a random variable equal to the time (in minutes) when the dishes are washed.

I assume by the probability being "linear" (between 0 and 100 minutes) you mean, for any random variate `t`:

```
P[T <= t] = .01*t, 0 <= t <= 100
```

If the dishes have not been washed at time `t0`, the (conditional) probability of the dishes being washed within the next two minutes is given by:

```
P[T <= t+2| T > t] = P[T <= t+2 and T > t] / P[T > t]
                   = (P[T <= t+2] - P[T <= t]) / (1-P[T <= t])
                   = (.01*(t+2) - .01t) / (1-.01t)
                   = 2/(100-t)
```

`P[T <= t+2| T > t]` reads, "the probability (the value of) `T` is less than or equal `t+2`, given that (the value of) `T` is greater than `t`".

Therefore:

```
P[T <=   2 | T >  0] = 2/98
P[T <=   4 | T >  2] = 2/96
...
P[T <=  98 | T > 96] = 2/4
P[T <= 100 | T > 98] = 2/2
```

If you drop the linearity requirement, for me, if we are talking dishes:

```
P[T <= 98] #=> 0
```

Comment: It hadn't occurred to me to interpret this with Bayes' Theorem. Nice answer.